# Jquery scrollTop animation not working .... "Cannot read property 'top' of undefind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery animation scrollTop is not working. When i click `<a>` it only takes me to the anchor without any animation. Can someone suggest any solution for this? When i run the web page, the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"` was displayed.

Here my html code :

```
<div class="BackgroundImg"></div>
<head>
    <title>Ryan Robert 1.0</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" >

         $(function(){
          $("a").click(function(){
             if(this.hash){
                 var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

                 var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
                 var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

                 $("html,body").animate({
                     scrollTop : toPosition         
                 },2000,"easeOutExpo");

                  return false;
             }

             });

      });
    </script>
```

body part:

```
        <ul>
            <li><div id="menus">
                .home</div></li>
            <li><a href="#secondBox"><div id="menus">
                .project</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#thirdBox"><div id="menus">
                .skills</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#forthBox"><div id="menus">
                .contact</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="firstBox">
        <div id="profileDescriptionBox">
            <div id="profileDescription">
                <h1>.Welcome!</h1>
```

Comment: The only way you'd get that error, is if the anchor doesn't have the same name as the href, and `$toElement` is empty.

Comment: i uploaded my html body part , the <a href=""> does work.. when i click it .. i take me to the correct part of the page but the problem is the scroll animation does not run..

Comment: There is no anchor with the name you're looking for? You're doing `$("a[name="+hash+"]")` and that searches for `<a name="secondBox"></a>` and there's no such thing.

Comment: oh i see, so any suggestion what i going to change?

Comment: Well, if you're trying to get the clicked anchor, it's already in `this`, so `var $toElement = $(this);` if you're trying to get something else, make sure the selector matches the element, and that it actually has the name you're trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you don't use prevent default!

So you are actually getting anchored like the default in the browser.

For a smooth animate I would suggest you do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var offset = $(this.hash).offset();
      if (!offset) {
       return;
      }

      $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop : offset.top         
      },2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#first-box">First box</a></li>
  <li><a href="#second-box">Second box</a></li>
  <li><a href="#third-box">Third box</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="first-box" class="box">
   First box
</div>
<div id="second-box" class="box">
   Second box
</div>
<div id="third-box" class="box">
   Third box
</div>
<div class="box">
 Just extra to fill out
</div>
```

Or jsfiddle.net

https://jsfiddle.net/4xuvjuq5/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `offset().top`?

```
var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top;
```